# failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout: stderr: remount /, flags: 0x84000: permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I want to install Docker on my vServer. I followed the instruction on their [website](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) exactly and the installation was successful. The hoster of my server offers an extra option I have to check when I want to use Docker. But it didn't do a single thing. But I don't believe this is actual a hoster problem.

So my command history looks like this:

```sh
[...]
root@vps-foo123:~# apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
[...]
root@vps-foo123:~# su droneci  
droneci@vps-foo123:/root$ cd

# This here is important
droneci@vps-foo123:~$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
1b930d010525: Extracting [==================================================>]     977B/977B
docker: failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: remount /, flags: 0x84000: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
droneci@vps-foo123:~$
```

The user `droneci` here is in group `docker` but the same thing happens to root. This is actually my first time doing anything with Docker.

On my computer, where Manjaro is running, everything works out of the box.

Here are just some specs of my server if this is helpful:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS x86_64
Docker: 18.09.7 (Docker Engine is the same)
Linux kernel: 4.15.18-14-pve
RAM: 2GB
CPU: 2GB
```

I searched all over the internet but I couldn't find anything related.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is actual not an answer but suddenly it worked. I don't know why but suddenly I was able to run `docker run hello-world`.

I think this was actual a hoster problem.